# Use SQL Certificate from another database

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, certificate

I have database `A` in this database there is a certificate and a table. I want to insert an encrypted value into a table which is in database `A`. The stored procedure is in database `B` and would ideally make a call like this:

```
EncryptByCert(Cert_ID('CertifiacteName'), 'SecretData')
```

This will always fail, because database `B` cannot find the certificate in database `A`

Without moving the stored procedure or the certificate, how can I create an encrypted value in database `B` using a certificate in database `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the EncryptByCert call in a function that lives in database A like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyEncrypt(@Data VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT ENCRYPTBYCERT(CERT_ID('MyCert'),@Data) EncryptedData;
```

To insert data into your table in database A while connected to database B use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseA.dbo.MyTable(id,EncryptedData)
VALUES(42, (SELECT EncryptedData FROM DatabaseA.dbo.MyEncrypt('testvalue')) );
```