# Moving an encrypted column to different server

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, certificate

Much like the question in "[Use SQL Certificate from another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611199/use-sql-certificate-from-another-database)", but this time, I am moving the database to another server. How to move the necessary certificates along, to guarantee that the same code still works?

```
EncryptByCert(Cert_ID('CertifiacteName'), 'SecretData')
```

Comment: Could this be the answer? http://www.sql-questions.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-Security/30238935/master-key-issue.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your certificates is in your database backup.

Also- most possible your certificates are encrypted by Database Master Key. So what you need is to make your Database Master Key (DMK) work on target instance.

By default, DMK is protected by password AND Service Master Key (SMK). And by default, key is opened automatically. That means, if you have rights to use certificate, its decrypted automatically when you need it.

As on new instance your SMK is different, it can not happen automatically. but you can open DMK by password. So what you need- move your DB, open master key, alter it so, that it is encrypted by new server SMK [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174433.aspx).

what you need to do on new instance:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'your password (from previous instance)'
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
```